# What are some open-sourced encryption libraries that depend on strictly libc and would be easy to implement into a small microcontroller?

Tags: security, encryption, assembly, libc

I am looking for some open-sourced encryption libraries to be ported over to a different platform. The platform only has the libc library availible and it would require me to reimplement the algorithms in assembly language. Preferably ones that avoid floating-pointer operations (simply due the the MCUs limitations) and that you think would be easier to rewrite using a simple instruction set like PIC16F

I am looking for some basic functions like
Hashing & public private key encryption.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very uncommon for cryptographic libraries to make use of floating point.

[PolarSSL](https://polarssl.org/) is very clean, modular, written in C, with no external dependencies. It's easy to extract the routines you need.

Of course, bear in mind that it is GPLv2. A commercial license is available too though.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your advice despite this question being closed, you have given me a good lead. I think I am gonig to go with LibTomCrypt just due to simplicity of legal issues its use of the WTFPL (Do what the f*** you want to public license.) Actually, I am not even joking, it uses this license xd

Answer (score 1):

I've used [LibTomCrypt](http://libtom.org/?page=features&whatfile=crypt) for AVR32. It's fast, it's small and it works :)